# Problem generating a random sequence of binary numbers

Tags: c++, random

```
#include <iostream>
#include <random>
#include <string>
#include <chrono>

using namespace std;

string string_maker5000(int length)
{
    unsigned seed = std::chrono::steady_clock::now().time_since_epoch().count();
    default_random_engine e(seed);
    string stringcheese;
    for (int i = 1; i <= length; i++)
    {
        uniform_int_distribution<int> distr(0, 1);
        int n = distr(e);
        stringcheese = ": ";
        stringcheese += n;
    }
    return stringcheese;
}
int main()
{
    string yee = string_maker5000(5);
    cout << yee << endl;
}
```

Whenever I run the program, instead of it outputting 1s and 0s it outputs question mark boxes for the 1s I think, and it appears to output 0s as blanks. I'm not really sure. Makes me think its some type of problem with utf or something.

[image]

Comment: 1) You're overwriting string on each iteration. 2) Prefer `std::bernoulli_distribution` to `uniform_int_distribution<int>(0, 1)`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Integers `0` and `1` are not the same as the digits (characters) `'0'` and `'1'`. Try this instead

```
stringcheese += n + '0';
```

By adding the integer to the zero digit you convert the integer to the required character.